# Result on $X_1, X_2$ random variables defining the same $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

Consider $X_1, X_2$ random variables taking values in $\{1, \dots, N\}$ and defining the same $\sigma$-algebra in their domain. I nedd to show that there is a permutation $\tau \in S_N$ that that, for all $j \in \{1, \dots, N\}$, $\{X_1 = j\} = \{X_2 = \tau(j)\}$. I know that $\{X_1 = j\} = \{ X_2 \in A\}$ for some $A \subseteq \{1, \dots, N\}$, but I am not sure how to prove that $A$ must be a singleton.

Comment: The reverse statement $\{X_2 = k\} = \{X_1 \in B\}$ also holds.

Comment: I don't quite see how to follow from your comment